# In DDD & CQRS, proper design on syncing read model with multiple aggregate updates

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Suppose I have 2 aggregates `Staff` and `Shop` , I have a a read model `StaffModel`  which contains shop information (shopId, name, address,etc) in a denormalized view.

A business rule is to create a `Staff` and a `Shop` in a single request, So I have a `CreateStaffService` that creates a Staff and fires `StaffCreatedEvent` , then `CreateShopService` listeners for `StaffCreatedEvent`, creates a `Shop`, then fires `ShopCreatedEvent`

On the read model side, I have 4 ways for designing the synchronizer service:

1. Subscribe to `StaffCreatedEvent`, create a record of `StaffModel`. then subscribe to `ShopCreatedEvent`, update store infomation on the `StaffModel` using staffId.
2. `ShopCreatedEvent` contains staff information, the synchronizer service subscribes to the event and insert the complete read model in one go. But the staff information is not relavant to the `Shop` aggregate, is it ok to include it in the event?
3. Model `StaffModel` and `ShopModel` separately, update models in response to corresponding aggregate events.
4. Wrap `CreateStaffService` and `CreateShopService` in a single transaction, fire a `StaffAndShopCreatedEvent`

I personally prefer option 2 and 4 as with option 1 it is difficult to ensure `StaffCreatedEvent` always arrives before `ShopCreatedEvent`.

Please share your ideas and experiences on this subject.
Thanks

**Updated:**

To avoid out of order event consumption using a sequence number, lets say I am generating a sequence number using a database sequence, incrementing by 1 each time, then suppose my subscriber consumes event 1, so the last processed event sequence is 1. Then producer publishes event 2 , event 3, and event 4 in order and events are sent only if the current transaction succeeds. So if transaction 2 creates a sequence number 2, but the transaction failed and rolled back , event 2 were not sent,  but event 3 and event 4 were successfully sent.

On the consumer side, both event 3 and event 4 are more recent than the last processed event 1, and event 2 will never come. So checking `lastProcessed + 1 == currentVersion` is wrong in this case unless the event sequence numbers (version) are strictly sequential, which is also difficult to gurantee.

Comment: Is your read model linearized, meaning that it runs sequentially on a single thread and there is no competing event consumption? In that case it's easy to go with #1 even if events may be out of order. Also, the way you describe the write side, waiting for events to happen in a specific order means that surely those events will have a sequence number in the right order which should be used to order events for the read model.

Comment: @Jay Just curious - why did you model `Staff` and `Shop` as two separate aggregates? There's something weird about `StaffAndShopCreated` IMO. Do they have the same lifespan?

Comment: Hi @guillaume31,the example is modeling a retail company which has Staff and Shops, Staff belongs to the company, and can be assigned to a Shop and associates a ShopStaff. The business case i described should be create staff -> create shop -> assign staff to the shop, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is staff singular, i.e. the group of people who work there, or is it more like a `StaffMember`? Can a new `Staff` be reassigned to a `Shop` later or do they have the same lifespan? I'm asking because putting them in the same aggregate would make things a lot easier. If there's a permanent one-to-one relationship between Staff and Shop, Shop can perfectly be the Aggregate Root that controls all invariants for the shop, including Staff ones.

Comment: In other words - the extra complexity of having 2 events is only worth it if someone cares about the distinction between `Shop` and `Staff`. Since your question doesn't mention any Staff events that happen at a different time than a Shop event, we could conclude that no one cares and they can be equated with each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined two distinct aggregates, which also could be within their own bounded contexts.  With events, each event should describe a single aggregate.  Most documentation and examples that you will see show a singular aggregate identifier.  Remember, that while you are looking at the creational aspect of your events right now, it is still just a delta - in this case going from "nothing" to "something".

A lot of frameworks deal with what your primary concern is, which is dealing with out of order events.  It is a real concern, especially with distributed systems.  To mitigate this, events are generally given a sequential identifier on the write side, and then the denormalizers will be fed events in order.  So, if event 4 arrives, and only event 2 has been processed, it will hold event 4 until after event 3 has been processed.

Here is a generalized discussion around the same issue: [Handling out of order events in CQRS read side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703348/handling-out-of-order-events-in-cqrs-read-side)

It sounds like you are rolling your own framework, which can be daunting.  I am in the process of doing the same, but it is more for expanding knowledge than plans to use in a real-world setting.  What I can posit for you, however, is consider how to get events to arrive more predictably.  If you are not looking at scaling out right now, then you could mitigate a lot of your concern by making sure that you push events into a FIFO queue.  Then, your synchronizer service could then poll the queue, instead of subscribing to events.  Couple this with sequencing your events for replay when you rebuild your aggregates, and you have a good starting point.  Doing this, you will not actually have to worry about out of order events unless you have multiple processes polling your queue.

To ensure that you are actually generating your events in sequence, what you describe sounds like a good use case for a domain service.  You are coordinating the operations of two aggregates.  Raising those events from your domain service helps you to make sure that operations on both aggregates have been completed.

**Updated:**

I'll expand a bit to reflect the additional question.  Let's start by taking a step back.  On the write side, you are never persisting your aggregates.  You are persisting the events that reflect the state changes, which includes creation.  You goal is that you will issue a command, the command will be given to the aggregate, and the aggregate will create an event from the command.  Once creating the event, the aggregate will apply it to itself, and then make it available for the command handler to retrieve from the aggregate.  Since that event is all that the aggregate needs to know to change state, that is all we will have to save to the write side.  When we need that aggregate again, we simply will load all of the events related to a given aggregate identifier and replay them against the aggregate class.  Once all events are replayed, you have hydrated your aggregate.

When your command handler passes the event to your event store, it only cares that it is an event.  On the persistence aspect, you will have the event likely serialized in a specific field, and additional fields that contain metadata around the event; such as the aggregate identifier and the type of aggregate (which makes querying easier, when you need to replay).  Additionally, the event will have a sequential identifier.  This is a good place for your autoincrementing identifier.  And, it is very important, that you have continuity there.

For the largest portion of what you are doing, you will end up inserting just a single event at a time.  In all likelihood, it will constitute a majority of your operations.  The elegance of this is that there is almost no chance of failure.  Since the events are just a stream of deltas, there is no referential integrity, to speak of.  There are more complex scenarios that you may encounter, primarily through the use of sagas or process managers, where you can potentially maintain the state of several aggregates before publishing their events to your event store.  How you do this can range from simple to complex.  Your primary difficulty here, though, will be in making sure that the aggregates have not been mutated by other events that have happened outside of the scope of the process manager/saga.  That is pretty much beyond the scope of what you are asking, though.  I'll provide a good resource for that to read up on, in closing.

Back to the event stream.  Since you are just pushing events out to your write side, and we can assume that they are created sequentially, the potential for out of order events come in when you are doing your projections.  Most commonly, this will happen in a scaled out deployment, where you have multiple servers picking commands off of a queue and distributing them.  After your event store pushes your event to your write side for persistence, it will push it out to the event bus, where your subscribers will act on them.  This is where ordering becomes important, as this is where your read side will be updated.

Taking your case, let's say that event 1 is creating Staff and event 2 is creating Shop.  If they were to hit the event bus in the opposite order, you would need to know that.  The goal of your event bus is to deliver your event somewhere, and that is commonly a queue.  A simple FIFO queue would actually present a problem at this point, because you are in a situation where you are mimicking the order received.  Your queuing mechanism should have the ability for you to inspect all queued items, and you will need to track the last processed event.  On a virgin system, with your two requests, whatever is monitoring the queue knows that the last processed event was 0.  It sees 2 arrive and does nothing.  Then 1 arrives, and it can push event 1 out to all subscribers, update the numeric value that tracks the last processed event to 1, dispatch event 2, and update the internal tracker to 2.  Essentially, you are looking at some sort of service that monitors the queue that the event bus publishes to, and then does an explicit dispatch to the subscriber(s) for each event.

I had mentioned a resource that covers a lot of this, and that is [Microsoft's CQRS Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx), a part of their Patterns & Practices series.  Even if you are not on a Microsoft stack, it has a lot of great information in it.  The best part is that it truly is a "journey".  You don't just get code samples and why you should do it, but you get to see the evolution of a project in a quasi-real-world application.  The entire book is available for download for free, as a PDF.  You can also get the paper book, if you so choose.  (I did, because there is something about the tactile feel of tech books and the way that I find myself flipping through them that is just not conducive to e-books).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I edited my questing and added another question on sequence number approach

Comment: Sorry, @Jay.  I see where I may have introduced some confusion in my answer.  I'll provide you with an updated answer tomorrow.

Comment: wow, that is excellent!  makes great sense, certainly clears a lot of my confusion on ddd & event sourcing & cqrs. I've downloaded the pdf you mentioned and started reading, may come up with other questions for discussion later.   Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @JosephFerris you have shed light on multiple publishers and event ordering, can you also shed some light on multiple consumers and ensuring correct event order processing, assuming that events are present in the desired order in the queue.