# How to handle out of order microservice messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, microservices

We have adopted an AWS powered microservice architecture where different sorts of payloads enter the system with a UUID and *type* via **mysql.lambda_async** from our database.

The problem is, that we've noticed that messages can come out of order. Imagine the scenario with the following type of message:

1. DEASSIGN_ROLE
2. ASSIGN_ROLE

When the actual intention was a quick toggle:

1. ASSIGN_ROLE
2. DEASSIGN_ROLE

Now we have a user with the wrong (elevated) permissions.

I've done some cursory research and for example answers like [Handling out of order events in CQRS read side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703348/handling-out-of-order-events-in-cqrs-read-side) suggest using sequence numbers.

Introducing a sequence number would be quite hard as we have many different types of messages. A sequence number would require a syncronous counter, where we have gone great pains to be simply asynchronous. Bear in mind, our system that generates the message is an SQL trigger ultimately.

Are there simpler solutions I am missing?

Comment: Have you considered SQS FIFO queues? Guaranteed exactly once delivery to the consumer (Lambda?), in first-in, first-out order. https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Comment: I haven't considered it, but mysql.lambda_async goes into lambda and then puts it on the (FIFO) queue. I am still concerned there is a possibility out of orderings can happen there.

Comment: When publishing the messages, the Lambda that is triggered by mysql.lambda_async should wait until it gets confirmation that message 1 was delivered to the queue before proceeding to publish message 2 to the queue.

Comment: "FIFO SQS queue is not supported as an event source"... oh dear.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is an unsolvable problem :

- you want to be full asynchronous
- you need sequentiality in your results

We had the same problem as yours, and we ended by setting sequences by type of messages.

Trying to be asynchronous and parallel when possible (according to message types/topics)